# Is there a way to run boost::process::child with sudo previlage by passing in the password?

Tags: c++

On the terminal I can do something like

```
echo <password> | sudo -S ping www.google.com -c 3
```

but I am not sure how I can bring this within the c++ code using boost process.

```
bp::child(bp::search_path("ping"),"www.google.com -c 3",bp::std_out << output)
```

this works perfectly fine, but when I try to do something like

```
bp::child(bp::search_path("echo"),"password","|","sudo -S ping www.google.com -c 3",bp::std_out << output)
```

it gives an error.
I tried using `bp::search_path("sh")` to run the shell and pass the command, but this also gives and error saying cannot execute binary executables.
Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: You could make a smaller script with a setuid bit that ran `ping` for you. Or make the program run as a user with a NOPASSWD entry for ping. Or have a separate privileged process that you communicate with over a pipe. This is a linux privilege issue, and there are quite a few alternatives to storing a password as plaintext.

Comment: Writing a password in a program's command line arguments is dangerous (at least with default settings in linux) since it will be visible to all users/programs on the system. Use setuid or sudoers as suggested above instead and make sure that there is no obvious potential for privilege escalation from the command that will be run. (For example allowing NOPASSWD in sudoers for a `sh` invocation is a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

The security remarks to your question are fair. But, I can assume that what you are trying to do should look like this:

```
bp::child(bp::search_path("/usr/bin/bash"),"-c 'echo <password> | sudo -S ping www.google.com -c 3'",bp::std_out << output)
```